# Getting wxStaticBitmap in BoxSizer

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I try to ask not to localized, because I think many other wxWidgets users will stumble about this problem or a similar one.

I try to get a wxStaticBitmap (original a PNG-Image) in a GUI, I will try to model it:

```
text text text
text text text
   IMAGE
   text
   text
```

How I can do this? When I try:

```
wxBitmap bild(_T("Bild.png"), wxBITMAP_TYPE_PNG);

wxStaticBitmap *image = new wxStaticBitmap(this, wxID_ANY,
    wxBitmap("Bild.png", wxBITMAP_TYPE_PNG),    
    wxPoint(100,100),                           
    wxSize(bild.GetWidth(), bild.GetHeight()));
```

The image will take over the hole window, even the wxNotebook, which contains the wxPanel, will disabled and I have only the image, but nothing else...

I want to get the image in the third row of the VerticalBox. Is there any way to make this happend?

-Casisto

(wxW: 2.9.4; C++-Compiler: g++)

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing special about `wxStaticBitmap` and you absolutely don't need to put it inside a panel. You do need to create it with the correct parent, if `this` in your example refers to `wxFrame`, it's not going to work if you then put it inside a `wxPanel` sizer, for example.

P.S. Do get rid of `_T` in your code, it's completely unnecessary in 2.9+. You also probably don't want to load the bitmap twice...

Comment: Hi VZ, I still use the _T because I think it's look better and for other programers who are used with older wxW-Versions it makes less complications. Is there any other way to get the full size Picture when I don't can use the GetWidth()/GetHeight() to a first bitmap implementation?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i found the answer myself:
I've to use a "subpanel" which will be the parent of the StaticBitmap

so it's this structur:

```
panel << vbox << Text  
         vbox << panel_2 << Image
         vbox << Text
```